# Time to send SDO

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I am working on CANopen architecture and had three questions:

1- When the 'synchronous window' is closed until the next SYNC message, should we send the SDO message? Can we not send a message during this period?

2- Is it possible not to send the PDO message during the simultaneous window?

3- What is the answer that the slaves give in the SYNC message?

[image: CANopen SYNC & Synchronous Windows Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have exact answers but I just wanted to share my assumptions & thoughts.

1. CiA 301 doesn't mention the relation between *synchronous window* and SDOs. In normal operation after the initial configuration, one may assume that SDOs aren't present on the system, or at least they are rare compared to PDOs. Although not strictly necessary, SDOs are generally initiated by a device which has the *master* role, and that device also produces the SYNC messages (again, it's not strictly necessary but it's the usual/common implementation). So, the master device may adjust the timing of SDO requests according to the *synchronous window*.

Here is a quote from CiA 301:

> If the synchronous window length expires all synchronous TPDOs may be
> discarded and an EMCY message may be transmitted; all synchronous
> RPDOs may be discarded until the next SYNC message is received.
> Synchronous RPDO processing is resumed with the next SYNC message.

2. CiA 301 uses the word **"may"** (see the quote above). So I'm not sure if it's mandatory or not. In my opinion, it makes sense to follow the advice and abort synchronous TPDO transmissions after the *synchronous window* and send an EMCY message. Event-driven (non-synchronous) TPDOs can be sent within or after the *synchronous window*.
3. There is no direct response to SYNC messages. On SYNC reception, SYNC consumers (slaves) sample their inputs, drive their outputs according to the previous RPDOs, and start transmitting their TPDOs containing the previous samples (or the current ones? I'm not sure about this).

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous windows are for specific PDO synchronization only. For hard real-time systems, data might be required to arrive within certain fixed time intervals - not too early, not too late. That is, it acts as a real-time deadline. If such features are enabled, you need to take that in consideration when doing the specific CANopen bus implementation.

For example if some SDO communication would occupy the bus so that the PDO can't meet its time window, that would be a problem. But this is easily solved by giving the PDO a lower COBID than the SDO, which should already be the case in most default device profile setups like "DS401 GPIO module". Other than that, you would have to make sure there is no ridiculous bus loads or that nodes hang up or get busy doing other things.

In systems with hard real-time requirements you probably don't want to allow any SDO communication during operational mode to begin with.

> What is the answer that the slaves give in the SYNC message?

That question doesn't make any sense. You need to study what the SYNC message does and what it is for.

Comment: Exactly, I realized, Thanks a lot.